# An ArrayList contains two elements, how to return only the String element?

Tags: java, arraylist, return

I'm pretty new to Java but I feel like this is an easy task. This arraylist has two elements...names and scores. I want to write a method that prints a list of all the names in the list, not the scores. I know I've done this before I just can't remember how lol

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Print test scrose and student names as well as he average for the class.
 */
public class TestScores {
  private ArrayList<Classroom> scores;
  public int studentScores;

  /**
   * Create a new ArrayList of scores and add some scores
   */
  public TestScores() {
    scores = new ArrayList<Classroom>();
  }

  /**
   * Add a new student and a new score.
   */
  public void add (String name, int score) {
    scores.add(new Classroom(name, score));
    if(score > 100){
      System.out.println("The score cannot be more than 100");
    }    
  }

  /**
   * Return all the student names.
   */
  public void printAllNames() {//this is the method.
    for (Classroom s : scores){
      System.out.println(scores.get(name));
    }
  }
}
```

and the classroom class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * This class creates the names and scores of the students
 */
public class Classroom {
  public int score;
  public String name;

  /**
   * Constructor for the Class that adds a name and a score.
   */
  public Classroom(String aName, int aScore) {
    score = aScore;
    name = aName;
  }

  /**
   * Return the name of the students
   */
  public String returnName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * Return he scores
   */
  public int returnScore() {
    return score;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void printAllNames() {//this is the method.
  for (Classroom s : scores){
    System.out.println(s.returnName());
  }
}
```

You should be precice in your question, your list does not contain 2 elements - names and scores - but multiple `Classroom` objects which contain names and scores.

Alternative answer using Java 8 streams:

```
scores.stream().map(c -> c.returnName()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely understand!